# Web Server Does Not Allow Using Post Method

Tags: c#, javascript, html, http

I want to connect a website with my user id and password and get my datas from website and store them in a text file, but I get error 405 that Method Not Allowed. Can somebody help me to figure out this?
Here is the html code of webserver:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>blablbablablabl</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function login() {
    setTimeout('window.close()',1000);
} 
</script>
<body>
<div><h3>blablablaasdasd</h3><form onSubmit="javascript:login();" style='margin-  top:10px;' id='loginPageForm' action='http://website.com' method='post' target='_blank'
<div>
<input name='t:ac' type='hidden'  value='$002f$002website.com$002fclient$002fdefault$002fsearch$002faccount$003f'  />
<input name='t:formdata' type='hidden' value='H4sIAAAAAAAAAJWQv0oDQRDGx4NAMJ1gEURstN2zMI02BkEQDgkc1mFvb7xs2Ntdd/ZMbKx8CRufQKz0CVLY+Q4+gI2FlYV7J6Lg/274mJnv932XD9CarMAyIXdiFA+4d0YnppB6czysCJ3mJZKDnnEF45aLETLPLZJ3Jz0mjEMlM5ZxQtbPgsiF35Wo8tUUfWXXDmad+8Xb5wjmEugIo8N3tR8+elhIxvyYx4rrIk69k7rYmloP8++uf8Hq/xdr4IxAorTKSkkkjZ5d5RuHTxd3EcDUfmtpOdHEuJyO4BSgwXyTfr2pT1qTJeh+sUU1hw9Btn8MIkxpjUbtiTXk/nOO8/Sxe3N9thNBlEBbKBm29xrvunpUWAahrr6R6qrbr+bD9Q/jCx9ggTUPAgAA' /></div>
<label for='identity'>Card Number:</label><div><input type='text' name='j_username'  /</div>
<div style='clear:both;'></div>
<label for='password'>Password:</label>
<div><input name='j_password' type='password' class='pass' value='' /><input type='submit' value='Login' /></div></form></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the C# code that I am trying to reach server.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://website.com/file.html");
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;  
        request.Timeout = 10000;           // timeout 10s
        request.Method = "POST";

        String formContent = "t:ac=$002f$002website.com$002fclient$002fdefault$002fsearch$002faccount$003f&t:formdata=H4sIAAAAAAAAAJWQv0oDQRDGx4NAMJ1gEURstN2zMI02BkEQDgkc1mFvb7xs2Ntdd/ZMbKx8CRufQKz0CVLY+Q4+gI2FlYV7J6Lg/274mJnv932XD9CarMAyIXdiFA+4d0YnppB6czysCJ3mJZKDnnEF45aLETLPLZJ3Jz0mjEMlM5ZxQtbPgsiF35Wo8tUUfWXXDmad+8Xb5wjmEugIo8N3tR8+elhIxvyYx4rrIk69k7rYmloP8++uf8Hq/xdr4IxAorTKSkkkjZ5d5RuHTxd3EcDUfmtpOdHEuJyO4BSgwXyTfr2pT1qTJeh+sUU1hw9Btn8MIkxpjUbtiTXk/nOO8/Sxe3N9thNBlEBbKBm29xrvunpUWAahrr6R6qrbr+bD9Q/jCx9ggTUPAgAA&j_username=johndoe0&j_password=12345";

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formContent);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
       // Get the response ...
        WebResponse response;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();//ERROR OCCURS HERE!!! 
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        richTextBox1.AppendText(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(reader.ReadToEnd()));
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
```

EDIT: Problem solved, found another URL in that website that allows POST method.

Comment: That mean you have the wrong URL.

Comment: I didnt use exact address I have changed it when changing I made a mistake. I fixed it now

Comment: Please show the signature and code for the method that you are posting to

Comment: Please post more info about his server side code & architecture

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a WebService or plain HTML file?

Comment: I am trying the fill the info at html code to enter to website as a user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@GSiry's solution is probably the way to go if you control the server you fetch data from.

Otherwise, the issue is about adjusting your request to whatever HTTP method the remote server accepts: Method Not Allowed is supposed to mean that server won't take some particular methods while accepting others, and for good reasons. See more on [request safety and idempotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Safe_methods).

What happens if you use GET instead of POST?

**EDIT**: Assuming you are really POSTing to the same web URL from both the HTML form and your C# request (which does not seem to be the case anyway), the reason why it behaves differently is not obvious and is in fact server implementation-dependent. Which means we can only do guesswork (for example, it might not like the [user agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-agent) it gets (or lack thereof) from your C# code.

Anyway, I stand by the advice of using GET. There seems to be no reason at all to issue a POST request, since you don't intend to modify `website.com/file.html`, which is the stated purpose of POST method.

**EDIT2**: Its not necessary to use POST for a login *per se*. HTTP authentication can be performed through form parameters, through HTTP request headers or through the own authoritative part of the domain name (http://username:password@website.com/your_file.html). But this depends exclusively on the concrete server implementation.

If you can't access the server logs, I'm afraid you're in for some trial-and-error session. Start by mimicking the browser's request **exactly**. Firebug, Chrome's or Safari's developer console will be your friends to see exactly what headers are being passed along with the browser request so that the POST method is allowed.

On a side note, what you **should** be using for authentication procedure is SSL/TLS (**https**://...)

Comment: I wish that he would post more info about his server side code & architecture

Comment: It works with GET method.I get all html code that I copied from website to my richtextbox object. But there is a thing that I can not understand in html code of web site next to the method there is a post method and with browser I post data to server and it works but why not works in C#? Please be understandful because I am very new in web coding.

Comment: Server is not mine and I know only the code above about server

Comment: Can post data to website with a browser is OK but can not post data with C# I really can not understand the logic behind this. Can somebody explain it please?

Comment: @user1895421 Read my edit: the reason why it behaves differently is not obvious and is in fact server implementation-dependent. Which means we can only do guesswork. Might be the user agent.

Comment: But I need to login system with my username and password so I need to POST.

Comment: @LexLythius Yes you are right I can login with parameters on URL but this web site is not working that way. Also it is not secured it is not using SSL it uses only HTTP. It works like this; enter pass and id then website.com redirects to another page that writes logging in then also this page redirects to desired page.

Comment: @user1895421 I see now. The problem was that POST requests in this particular page require either a server-side session (which you already have in the browser but did not generate from your C# code) or a [HTTP BASIC authentication header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) you were not providing. Glad you solved this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVC, it might be as simple as adding the

```
[HttpPost]
```

attribute to the controller function that accepts your post request

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to access a WebService add following section to target's site Web.config under System.Web:

```
<webServices>
   <protocols>
      <add name="HttpPost"/>
   </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Comment: I can not add this because server is not mine.

Comment: Well if you don't control it and cannot ask those who do to make the change, and server doesn't allow these requests - there's nothing you can do.